# Execute a trigger after research is complete

Tags: modding, map-editor, starcraft

I'm making a map where I want to destroy a building when it finishes researching a certain ability.

How do I create a trigger that accomplishes this?

Comment: If starcraft editor questions are allowed (and it seems to be) that is a perfectly valid question. Perhaps the downvoters could explain a bit what is wrong?

Comment: Putting starcraft or starcraft 2 in the tittle could help, i'm guessing the downvoters didn't see the tags.

Comment: He's excluding a big part of the people who could help him from the potential answerers group. Unless there's no scripting in a known language involved here, my -1 stays.

However, if it's only an editor without any programming, then I'll remove it, sorry.

Comment: @Yann Every question excludes potential answerers simply by existing. I can't make sense of the rest of your comment explaining why you voted down.

Comment: @Yannbane No, the scripting system of Starcraft is proprietary and not implemented in any well-known scripting language. It's a point&click system implemented in the map editors GUI. It is unlikely that anyone can answer this question who isn't familiar with the Starcraft map editor.

Comment: @Anko, a question that excludes people who can answer it isn't really a good question. I gave the -1 because I thought he used a familiar language for scripting, yet didn't provide any details. I was wrong, so I removed the -1, end of story.

Comment: IIRC, in Starcraft there's no explicit way to use triggers to even detect when a building has finished researching something.  Which specific ability are you trying to detect?  Is it for human players or computer players?

Comment: @researching burrow for a human player in the hatchery